# Xamarin - add a OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I implemented a class to create a custom control (like a tabbar). A IsSelected boolean is used to change some properties of that control.

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty IsSelectedProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomTabBar), false, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: IsSelectedPropertyChanged);



public static void IsSelectedPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = (CustomTabBar)bindable;
    if (control != null)
    {
       control.IsSelected = (bool)newValue;
       control.Update();
    }
}
```

I need to detect change in a parent view where this control is used, in order to show content accordingly on IsSelected or not.

I need to use  INotifyPropertyChanged?  how?

I use the INotifyPropertyChanged in the custom control class, and where I use it in the parent I put a listener:

```
PropertyChanged += (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    // logic goes here 

    Console.WriteLine("A property has changed: " + e.PropertyName);
};
```

but it's not fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need, is a good old custom event exactly how you would do it in C#.

First, you need to introduce the event in your custom control class:

```cs
public delegate void IsSelectedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event IsSelectedHandler OnSelected;
```

Then, you most likely want to raise the event in your property-changed callback method `IsSelectedPropertyChanged`:

```cs
public static void IsSelectedPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    if (OnSelected != null) 
    {
        OnSelected(this, new EventArgs(/* Whatever you want to publish here*/));
    }
}
```

With all the plumbing done, you're now able to subscribe to these events in the parent view, like so:

```cs
yourTabControl.OnSelected += delegate {
    // Logic goes here
};
```

Comment: Tx. code works if I change "this" for "sender " (and previusly define a " public static object sender { get; private set; }"
). Is that correct?

Comment: Do you get an error of some sort if you leave the code as it is (not replace `this` with `sender`)? In my code sample, I'm trying to signify that the sender that raised the event is `this` (reference to the current instance of your custom control class). By creating the `sender` property yourself and not assigning a value to it, you're effectively sending null as the sender. This means that if you have many instances of that custom control, you can't decipher which tab control raised the event. When setting sender to `this`, you have the reference to the control and can use it if you will.